# How to change build path for react-app-rewired

Tags: javascript, path, create-react-app, react-app-rewired

I am trying to change the build path for `react-app-rewired` in the file `config-overrides.json` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired/issues/201).

```js
module.exports = {
    paths: function (paths, env) {
        paths.appBuild = 'C:\\Projects\\jhipster\\src\\main\\webapp\\app';
        return paths;
    }
};
```

But it is not taken into consideration, and I receive the following error:

```
Could not find a required file.
Name: index.html
Searched in: C:\Projects\jhipster\public
```

I have hardcoded the path directly just to test if it's working.

Am I omitting something?

Answer (score 2):

The problem actually isn't related to the build path. The problem is that React expects there to be a `public/index.html` file but can't find any such file. I'm guessing you've either renamed the `public` folder or moved `index.html` somewhere else.

Solution: tell `react-app-rewired` where to find `index.html`.

```js
// config-overrides.json
module.exports = {
    paths: function (paths, env) {
        paths.appBuild = 'C:\\Projects\\jhipster\\src\\main\\webapp\\app';
        // Tell the app where our public folder is
        paths.appPublic = 'path_to_public_folder';
        // Tell the app where our index.html is
        paths.appHtml = 'path_to_index.html';
        return paths;
    }
};
```

Comment: Warning: the var name is misspelled in your example: `path` instead of `paths`.

Comment: Ah, thanks for noticing! I've fixed it now.